# UITableViewDelegate not called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having a weird behaviour here. I have a `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController` that is contained in a `UITabBarController`.

It's working fine all the time, except when I receive a notification from iMessage and open it. Then if I go back to the app using the top left `< MyApp`, then the `UITableView` delegate (more specifically the didSelectRow method) is not called anymore but I'm still able to scroll it.

If I receive notifications from other apps (like Duolingo and Inbox), open it and go back to app, it works fine, except with iMessage.

Has this happened to anyone here before?

I'm using Swift 3 and Xcode 8.1.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Here are some methods:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Here i'm just updating the navigation bar color
    if let navBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar as? NavigationBar {
        navBar.apply(color: colorRGB(33, 163, 161))
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    // Just making navbar trasnparent
    if let navBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar as? NavigationBar {
        navBar.applyTransparency()
    }
}
```

The table view is created in the storyboard and data source and delegate is assigned there too.

[image: Storyboard outlets]

Comment: Is your `UITableView` delegate reset in `viewWillAppear` or any other related methods?

Comment: @redent84 no, it's not

Comment: Can you post a minimum sample reproducing the issue? It may help tracking down the problem

Comment: Show where you set the `tableView`, the `delegate` and what is done in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Updated the question @shallowThought